# Javascript: Loadtext data from a text file to textbox (no buttons)

Tags: javascript, html, file, text, textbox

I'm trying to get the string from a textfile, located at the desktop on local PC. I mean **no** "open file" buttons needed. Just my google extension inhect the text box and the **text should be there on page load**. The variable that I need to get is **filetext**

The textfile is **kw.txt** contains

```
apple
carrot
potato
```

The script that supposed to get the variable **filetext** from the text file:

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', 'file:///C:/Users/224505/Desktop/kw.txt');
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
var filetext = client.responseText;
}
client.send();
```

Please help!

Comment: This doesn't work in most browsers, what is the purpose of this anyways? Maybe someone can give you alternative methods based on the purpose.

Comment: just making a chrome extension. I'll have an itembox and want the items to be taken from the text file, which is editable...

Comment: chrome extension docs has a method showing how you can access text file from within your extension, you should read it. Maybe when I'm using a computer I'll post an answer.